# Round app icon not displaying on Android Oreo

Tags: android, icons

I'm trying to set the round launcher icon for my app in Android Studio but it only displays the default icon when I test the app in an emulator running Oreo (API 27). I added icons using **Image Asset** and overwrote the images with ones generated from http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/.

I've specified `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` in my **manifest** file and made sure the icons are using the appropriate names in the **res** folders.

The default icon works fine on older OS versions. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 9):

If you are a non-fancy developer, this answer is for you:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

</application>
```

I have used same `icon` for icon and `roundIcon`. It solved my issue.
Plus, I don't understand why android have so many settings for application icon, older was better!!!

Answer (score 5):

You will go to **File->New->image Assert->legacy->** below header of google play store icon than select **circle** option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your suggestion but I still get the default Android icon with its head.

Comment: Thanks, this resolves my problem. Now it works and the round icon is displayed.

Comment: i agree best answer for me